# Can Android App automation testing be done using selenium webdriver and C#?

Tags: c#, android, selenium, webdriver

Can Android App automation testing be done using selenium webdriver and C#?
I am learning android automation testing. And from the data available on internet, i have installed Android SDK and Eclipse. I am just curious to know whether i can do the same using C# coding instead of Java? And if Yes where can i find more details to start with it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**For better and smooth running application i suggest you to go for manual testing instead of any ready made server tool**

Comment: hi, may i know your difference between manual and automation testing and why automation testing is used and which case we need automation testing instead of manual testing

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.  Have you looked at the selenium documentation about the android driver?

If not, follow this [link](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver)

Comment: Hi.. I did not follow more reading the details from the link above. Basically I am not able to find out how can do coding in C# for an android app, how will i run the tests? Where will i see the actual test running? As in selenium, a browser is displayed running the tests. Similarly here where will i see the test running? IS it on emulator or on device?